# How to delay parent component from rendering until a setState in child component has finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`**parent-component**`

```
    class MatchVideos extends Component {
        DaySelector = createRef();  //creating ref for child-component

        componentDidMount() {

            utils.getData().then((response) => {

            this.setState({ dayData: response.data }, () => {
                 this.getData(this.DaySelector.current.state.currentDay);  //calling a method in parent by passing child-component data
            });

            })
            .catch(err => {
               if (err.response) {
               this.setState({ isError: true })
               }
            })
       }

    render(){
       return(
       <DaySelector ref={this.DaySelector}/>
       )
    }
    }
```

`**child-component(DaySelector)**`

```
componentDidMount(){
        let data = {
            "trn_year": utils.trn_year,
            "trn_id": utils.trn_id
        }
        utils.getDay(data).then((response) =>{
            this.dates = response.data.dayWise;
            var curDay = this.dates.filter(function(day) {
                console.log(new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]);
                return( day.Date === "2019-01-19"
            )
            })
            this.setState({currentDay: curDay[0].Day, selectedDay: curDay[0].Day}, ()=>{  //this is the state I want to access in parent-component.
                utils.selected_day = this.state.selectedDay;
                utils.selected_date = curDay[0].Date;
            });                          
        })
    }
```

So we know componentDidMount of parent will be executed only after all the child components componentDidMount methods are executed. But my issue is 1 in 5 times the ref of Dayselector in parent method is empty(current: null). As you can see I'm using the state of child component(Day selector) in parent component. I think the issue is the setState in child method is taking some time, and the parent method meanwhile gets executed with null values. How to solve this issue? And correct me if I'm wrong or completely off-point in my question. All I need is the parent component should render after there is data in child-component.

*I'm showing only the necessary code for understanding my question*

Comment: Think in another way like hold a loading state variable at parent component and make it true so the value wont be null it will show loading once the value is there you can make it to false and pass the value to parent by using a callback function and show the value, will that work for you?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I didn't quiet follow. We are loading the data in parent based on the day selected in child.

Comment: @ dharani  can you create a codesandbox with minimum reproducable issue so it will be helpful to find it

Comment: have you tried moving the state logic in the parent itself and passing down the relevant props/functions to the child, it is one of the recommended approach from React Docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @n4m31ess_c0d3r Lifting the state up will work I'm guessing. Can you tell me how do I do that in my code context?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS sorry dileep, I'm on the clock. Appreciate your help though, thanks!

Comment: @n4m31ess_c0d3r mentioned lifting the state will be a helpful way but since if you can reproduce the issue it will be much more easy..

Comment: ah, one can only guess since there are many unknowns in the question like what are `utils` functions, what is causing the `parent` to re-render, what is being rendered in the `child`, what data in the parent is dependent on the child, how is the state `dayDate` being used etc. so the context could possibly be high level only. Maybe try codepen/jsfiddle, you can add react lib int it share some working code.As I see you could try 2 options - a) move the child logic into the parent, i.e. `utils.getDay` as both this call and `setState` are async call, so can'y expect them to wait till the parents`

Comment: b) pass a callback into the child from parent, some ` <DaySelector ... onChildLoad={() => (...)}`, and then call `onChildLoad` when the child data loads. Basically, move the parent's `componentDidMount` into `onChildLoad` callback and the `setState` inside this should re-render the parent. But b) seems to me counter-intuitive as it may start the render cycle of the child again, i'll try to do it as per option a).

Answer (score 0):

Hey React have these cool thing Called [React lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) and [React Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense)

For usage you check this cool video video from [Siddharth Kshetrapal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gJ29DMkqo0)